# Touch Up Inside not working properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, touch

I have an app with some buttons, when those buttons are pressed the image on them should change. I assume that the `TouchUpInside` runs when you tap and remove the finger while still holding inside the area of the element, however it only works rarely and I'm not sure why.

The reason I use `TouchUpInside` instead of `TouchDown` is because I want the user to be able to cancel the action.

I'm sorry if I've misunderstood anything about those events and if this has already been asked. I couldn't find an answer to my problem searching the web.

```
//The IBAction is set to trigger on TouchUpInside
@IBAction func action11(sender: UIButton) {
    setTile(sender)
}

func setTile(sender: UIButton) {
    if turn {
        print("O's turn")
        sender.setImage(xTile, forState: .Normal)
        turn = false
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added the necessary code

Comment: post your code. so that it will be easy to figure out.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: you can use highlighted or selected for changing while and after pressing .

Answer (score 0):

There are some properties of UIButtons which you can use to achieve what you want. 
You can use Default and selected state of uibutton to set two different images.

In XIB select state "Default" and assign default image to that state again select state to "Selected" and assign image which you want after button section.

and add following line in button selection method.

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender{
     sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm planning to use default and highlighted. However I think I just don't quite understand how this event works. As mentioned, sometimes when I press the button changes, so it does actually work, just not all the time. Can you explain how the `TouchUpInside` event works if I have gotten it wrong?

Comment: whenever you tap that button it will trigger ibaction which is connected to touchupinside. It simply work like button click. It will not change button state.. You have to manage it on your own ... If you are planning to use highlighted then use this        sender.highlighted = !sender.highlighted;

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct, you need to use touchUpInside.
I assume you are trying to create a button that has a toggle function. On one touch you want the button to have the value Say "X" and when touched again the button has a value "O".

Take a look at this code below, this should do the job.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var isButtonPressed = false{
    // Adding a Property Observer, that reacts to changes in button state
    didSet{
        if isButtonPressed{
            // Set the Value to X.

        }else{
            // Set the Value to O.
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func changeButtonValue(sender: UIButton) {
    // Toggle the button value.
    isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed
}

}
```

Comment: Button pressed, it says X and can't change value again. My problem is just that it's not always responding on being touched.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set `turn=true` after the first time, this code is executed it will be executed only one.

```
if turn {
    print("O's turn")
    sender.setImage(xTile, forState: .Normal)
    turn = false
}
```

Check if the button frame is large enough to get finger touch. 
Apple says at least 35x35 pixel.

Comment: The button is 100x100, and I have made sure to make it true again later in the code.